# Remove series border lines from plotly express area chart

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

`px.area` shows a line atop each area series. How can I remove it?

The [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/#overlaid-area-chart-without-boundary-lines) only shows how to remove lines from `go.Scatter` calls (with `mode='none'`).

Here's an example ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gQw4i_ZBoXUg3qxa3V1GUvINImt9ZBWm?usp=sharing)), where I'd like to remove the dark blue and red lines atop the light blue and red areas, respectively (to avoid the perception that the red series is nonzero where it stacks atop the blue series):

```py
import plotly.express as px

px.area(y=[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]])
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Plotly, how to remove background horizontal line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535785/python-plotly-how-to-remove-background-horizontal-line)

Comment: @EskandarAbedini no, I want to remove the dark blue and red lines atop the light blue and red areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC this is what you're looking for:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.area(y=[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]])
```

Before:

[image]

If you want `lines` same color as `traces`:

```
for i in range(len(fig['data'])):
  fig['data'][i]['line']['width']=0
```

[image]

If you want `traces` same color as `lines`:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(fillcolor = trace.line.color))
```

[image]

Comment: A simpler version of the data update snippet:
`for data in fig["data"]: data["line"]["width"] = 0`